# How do I properly render React components using conditionals if I need to show custom prompt first?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise

I'm making weather forecast application that needs 2 values (name and city) to render. That's why I want to make a popup appear on  site first after loading. Then if user enters proper city  - main component appears in place of popup. I wanted to use external library like Sweetalert2 but it doesn't allow double inputs.

I coded this component that uses fetch and conditionals, but it doesn't work. If promise is resolved successfuly it should change state "validation" to trigger rendering another component but when "this.setState({ validation: true })" is present, promise sends "error message" instead of "success" and nothing else happens

```
import React from 'react'
import App from './App.js';


class InputBox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: "",
            cityValue: "",
            errorMessage: "",
            key: 'x',
            validation: false
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({ cityValue: event.target.value })
    }
    handleSubmit(event) {


        fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + this.state.cityValue + '&appid=' + this.state.key)
        .then(function (resp) {
            return resp.json()
        })    
        .then(function (data) {
                if (data) {
                   
                      //  this.setState({ validation: true }) // if this is present, there is "error message" in console
                        console.log("success")
                    
                }
            })
            .catch(function () {
                console.log("error message")
                
            });


    }

    render() {
        let content
        if (this.state.validation == false) {
            content = <form
                onSubmit={
                    (e) => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        this.handleSubmit(this.state.cityValue);
                    }
                }
            >


                <input type="text" value={this.state.cityValue} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                <input type="submit" value="Send" />
            </form>
        } else {
            content = <App city={this.state.cityValue} />
        }

        return (
            <div>
                {content}
            </div>

        );
    }

}

export default InputBox
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ternary operator(?:) to achieve conditional rendering

```
render() {
    return {this.state.validation == false?(
        <form
            onSubmit={
                (e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    this.handleSubmit(this.state.cityValue);
                }
            }
        >
            <input type="text" value={this.state.cityValue} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <input type="submit" value="Send" />
        </form>):

        (<App city={this.state.cityValue} />)
}}
```

Comment: I used your code and it would work but promise still does change state even if there is successful fetch() response

Comment: Do you mean even if it fetch response and you trying to set state its throwing error? or its just not updating state value ?

Comment: Ideally state should get updated until unless API is not failing. just you need to uncomment                      ` //  this.setState({ validation: true }) `

and in case if you are facing any error while update please share same

Comment: I uncommented it and it's throwing "error message". When I comment setState it says "success" again and console.log(data) works.

Comment: Most probably I doubt its not due to state its due to App component you are trying to use. Because as soon you update state it will re-render component . Also if it would be error in set data so console.log which is being called post that should not have executed. So My understanding is whenever state gets true it goes to second part and that child component is not working properly. Also you can confirm same by trying to replace second part of condition(`<App city={this.state.cityValue} />`) with `<h1>It Works!!!</h1>`

Comment: hey good idea but it still doesnt work :/ I replaced second part of condition as you suggested but it still consoles "error message" whenever this.setState({validation: true}) is not commented.

Comment: hey I finnaly managed to fix it. The problem was that this.setState didnt work if there was no arrow function in resolving a promise. Thank you for your help anyway!

Comment: Oh right! I also missed that :( It will not work because functions statement will create its own this and in that function it wont have access to state. Anyways its worked  Great :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Conditional Rendering.

You can try any of the below ways to implement conditional rendering in react:

1. Using an if…else Statement
2. Using a switch Statement
3. Using Element Variables
4. Using Ternary Operators
5. Using Logical && (Short Circuit Evaluation)
6. Using Immediately Invoked Function Expressions (IIFEs)
7. Using Enhanced JSX Libraries

Refer Conditional Rendering in react docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html